# Cherrypicking versus Rebasing

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase, cherry-pick

The following is a scenario I commonly face:

You have a set of commits on `master` or `design`, that I want to put on top of `production` branch.

I tend to create a new branch with the base as `production` cherry-pick these commits on it and merge it to `production`

Then when I merge `master` to production, I face merge conflicts because even tho the changes are same, but are registered as a different commit because of cherry-pick.

I have found some workarounds to deal with this, all of which are laborious and can be termed "hacks".

Altho' I haven't done too much rebasing, I believe that too creates a new commit hash.

Should I be using rebasing where I am cherrypicking. What other advantages does that have over this.

Comment: Note: my answer is not compatible with branches you have already pushed (and people have puled from), since it changes the SHA1. But for a branch with recent content not yet push, it is a valid process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should make a `rebase --interactive` your design branch on top of production, where:

- you can reorder your commits, starting with the ones you need in production
- you can then merge production to the last commit of design you want to incorporate (fast forward)

```
    -x--x--x1--x--x2 (design)
      \
       p--p (production)
```

With x1 and x2 needing to be included in production:

```
git checkout design
git rebase --interactive production

-x
  \
   p--p (production)
       \ 
        x1'-x2'--x'--x' (design)
```

Then:

```
git checkout production
git merge x2'
-x
  \
   p--p--x1'--x2' (production)
                \
                 x'--x' (design)
```

That allows you:

- to validate current design commits against the production commits (durung the rebase)
- reorder the design commits
- include the first ones in production
- allows subsequent merges from design to production to be a fast-forward one.

---

[Lakshman Prasad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55562/lakshman-prasad) adds:

> I push the changes at the end of the day most of the time. So doesn't really help that much. How would your answer change for the pushed master branch

I would do the same, but with a private branch created just for the operation:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b master-private
```

```
    -x--x--x1--x--x2 (master, master-private)
      \
       p--p (production)
```

, then the rebase, this time with the private branch (i.e. a branch you won't ever push).

```
git rebase --interactive production

-x--x--x1--x--x2 (master)
  \
   p--p (production)
       \ 
        x1'-x2'--x'--x' (master-private)
```

Then:

```
git checkout production
git merge x2'

-x--x--x1--x--x2 (master)
  \
   p--p--x1'--x2' (production)
                \
                 x'--x' (master-private)
```

`master` won't benefit from the commit reordering (with a more logical order), but at least you can push `master` whenever you want.

And `production` can still include exactly what it needs.
If subsequent commits to `master` have the same issue (some need to be included to `production`, other will later), I would:

- delete `master-private` (we don't really care about those x', copy of x commits from master)
- make a `master-private` branch on top of master
- re-do the `rebase --interactive`, with a crude conflict resolution tactic (except for the first commits of that `master-private` branch, since those ones need to be integrated in the `production` branch)

```
    -x--x--x1--x--x2--x--x3--x (master)
      \
       p--p--x1'--x2'--x3' (production)
                   |     \
                   |      x''--x'' (master-private)
                    \
                     x'..x' (old x' from the first master-private)
```

Comment: VonC, I push the changes at the end of the day most of the time. So doesn't really help that much. How would your answer change for the pushed master branch.

Comment: @Lakshman: if you push but nobody pull, then it works. But if not, you need to have a special private branch you create on top of master, before "rebasing interactive" that same (private, i.e. not pushed) private branch on top of production.

Comment: @Lakshman: off course, that means you never merge master or design to production (since it will trigger lots of conflicts). You always rebase --interactive a private branch you make whenever you need one on top of master or design.