# Presenting a subset of commits on a branch as a github pull request

Tags: git

I forked a project on github.

I made commit 1,2,3,4 & 5 on my master branch.

I want to present commit 2 & 5 as a pull request to upstream, in such a way that when upstream accepts, and I sync my branch with upstream, I don't get any conflicts.

What are the various ways I could do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could:

- `fetch` the upstream branch
- [`rebase --interactive` your branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026218/how-to-use-git-rebase-to-clean-up-a-convoluted-history/3026393#3026393) on top of it, making sure commit 2 & 5 are re-ordered as commit 1 & 2
- submit those 2 commits as [pull requests to the fork queue](http://github.com/blog/270-the-fork-queue) of upstream project.

Comment: on the theory of `rebase --interactive`, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022409/cherrypicking-versus-rebasing/3022452#3022452